# SQL Syntax Error: "Missing Right Parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, oracle12c, ora-00907

I understand the ORA-00907 is indicating that I have a syntax error in my code, I just can't find it. Can someone help point out the problem? I'm using SQL Developer (Oracle12c).

```
CREATE TABLE equip 
  (equipid NUMBER(3),
   edesc VARCHAR2(30), 
   purchdate DATE, 
   rating CHAR(1), 
   deptid NUMBER(2) NOT NULL, 
   etypeid NUMBER(2),
    CONSTRAINT equip_equipid_pk PRIMARY KEY (equipid),
    CONSTRAINT equip deptid_fk FOREIGN KEY (deptid) REFERENCES dept (deptid),
    CONSTRAINT equip_etypeid_fk FOREIGN KEY (etypeid) REFERENCES etypes (etypeid),
    CONSTRAINT equip_rating_ck CHECK (rating IN ('A','B','C')));
```

[image: Oracle12 SQL Syntax Error]

Comment: Please post the code **as properly formatted text** - not a screenshots thereof......

Comment: Really, this is in the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Using screenshots for code makes it impossible for readers to copy & paste your code, and it makes it impossible for people who use screen readers.

Comment: Done. Added code properly formatted as text.  @marc_s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a space in the constraint name, which is probably confusing the syntax parser:

```
CONSTRAINT equip deptid_fk FOREIGN KEY (deptid) REFERENCES dept (deptid),
                ^
```

If you need a space in identifiers, delimit them in double-quotes like `"equip deptid_fk"`. But it's easier if you can spell your identifiers without whitespace or punctuation.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help. Can't believe I missed that.

Comment: @andrewbiddle -  In addition to this (correct) answer: pretty much any interface you use will tell you EXACTLY where the error was found (line of code and position on the line, or a marker like Bill is showing above). That should help you find and fix the mistakes yourself.

Comment: Oracle error messages are notoriously unhelpful. I didn't see this either, until I tried your statement in MySQL, and then it told me exactly where the problem was. :-)

Comment: @BillKarwin: thank goodness you had the SQL code to copy&paste! ;-)